# sqlcmd using windows authentication in automation script

Tags: batch-file, automation, sqlcmd

I am using below command in bat file to get some information from the list of sql instance,i am using -E to login as windows authentication when i manually triggering the bat file.

Could anyone help how to configure it on SQLJOB.i am sure that - E will not work on SQLjob ..

Thanks in advance!!

FOR /F %%G IN (E:\serverlist\serverlist.txt) DO (echo %%G
sqlcmd -S %%G -iE:\serverlist\some.sql -h-1 -W -w1000 -s "," -m1 -E >>E:\output\result.txt 
)

Comment: i have tried runas command but its not working

Answer (score 1):

using proxy account helped to resolve the issue.just add the sqlcmd command under a job step with Run as 'Proxy account'

Answer (score 1):

try this.

> sqlcmd -S .\sqlexpress -E  -i "c:\test.sql" -o "c:\output.txt"
> (This command would execute a SQL script on a local SQLExpress server using Windows Authentication)
>
> sqlcmd -S mysql -U sqluser -P sqlpassword  -i "c:\test.sql" -o "c:\output.txt"
> (This command would execute a SQL script on a SQL server using SQL authentication)